# IE6/7 Freezing during jQuery AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

I'm using the following code to call in some html, and display it. Most browsers seem to handle it fine, but IE6 and 7 freeze up. Unfortunately, the request can sometimes take more than a few seconds, so the delay is noticeable.

I'm also calling Fancybox on success, so that the returned html can have a link that launches a modal window.

Code:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'url',
      success: function(data) {
        $('#videolink').hide();
        $('#videolink').html(data).slideDown();
        $("a#video").fancybox({
           'hideOnContentClick': false,
           'transitionIn'       : 'elastic',
            'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
            'titleShow'         : false,
            'scrolling'         : 'no',
            'onStart': function() { _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Event Title', 'Value']); },
           'callbackOnClose': function() { $("#fancy_content").empty();}
        });
      }
    });
```

Is this the best way to handle the request?

Comment: What do you mean by "freeze up"? Do they just sit there doing nothing, or do you get an error dialog?

Comment: The screen doesn't respond. I can't scroll or navigate links on the page, for a few seconds until the Ajax content appears, then it's ok.

Comment: Much as I agree in theory, IE7 and IE8 seem to be having a similar issue, Jason. Also, 5% of an audience isn't worth ignoring entirely. My view on the IE6 support issue is to try to build the site so that it is at least usable in IE6, and great in everything newer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your iexplore process using 100% CPU? If yes, then the problem is with slow DOM manipulation by IE.
Try commenting out lines in success callback to check if you can find the offending one...